# Downloading html source code and loading it

Tags: java, android, html, web-testing

I found this code from here [download html source android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067827/download-html-source-android) . But when I try running it, my program keeps crashing. I have already added the internet permission in. Any ideas?

Edit:  Here is the full error message. 08-02 00:16:47.364: E/EmbeddedLogger(1577): Error getting package label: com.jimmyc.lawrenceh.schedulinglookup

Edit2: It works on Android 2.2 but it doesn't work on Android 4.0/3.0.

```
 private void initialize() {
      //initialize variables here
      try {
          getHtml();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public void getHtml() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.yahoo.com");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";

        BufferedReader reader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line + "\n";
            // Toast.makeText(Connect.this, line.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages when it crashes?

Comment: Edit: Here's the error message : 08-02 00:16:47.364: E/EmbeddedLogger(1577): Error getting package label:

Comment: @user1526556 Please update your question and add full error message from logcat

Comment: I believe it is a problem with the HTTP response using the execute function. I put a log after ea line and it seems to crash there. I didn't get an error from my logcat though.

Comment: It's working on an older tablet, but not one with android 4.0 or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to download the HTML code in the UI Thread. Try to download it in the background, using [AsynkTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Edit. If you say that it works on Android 2.2 but it doesn't work on Android 4.0/3.0 I'm completely sure you are trying to download it in the UI thread. From Android 3.0, [you can't do long process in the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/seamlessness.html#threads) because you can block it. You must do the download in a [different thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#ThreadSafe)

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You have to create an inner class in your Activity. This class have to extends of AsyncTask and you have to put the method `getHtml` in `doInBackground()`

Comment: For some reason, it works but then as soon as I uncomment out the toast, it crashes. Am I not allowed to have any toasts displayed from the background thread?

Comment: I think the Toast have to run in the UI Thread, try to put the toast in the `onPostExecute()`method