# Submitting a search on a website using JAVA

Tags: java, android, http, post

I am working on android application that searches food from http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calorie-chart-nutrition-facts. However I am very new to `JAVA`, and I am doing a lot of reading but I am still unsure. I believe I have to do something with `POST` requests but I have never done such thing as I have little programming experience. I currently using `JSOUP` in my `android app` and I don't know if that is all I need to do this. I simply need to make my program fill out the search field, submit the search and go to the first result(link) that is provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you extracting the data from html page using jsoup ?

Comment: After submitting the search and clicking the link, on the resulting page i would be extracting data...which I know how to...I am just unsure about the whole searching part.... (Why so many downvoted...just want help :( )

Comment: your question is not clear, thats why you got down votes,

Comment: however is that your website ?

Comment: The website i want to use is myfitnesspal...

Comment: Check on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067827/download-html-source-android

Comment: Sorry Sumighosh, not what I am looking for....thanks though

Comment: What do you meant by "I am just unsure about the whole searching part", you mean how to search for those contents from resultant string?

Comment: I mean how to input a string into the search field and submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this requires getting an API key since MyFitnessPal's API is private.

You will want to submit a request to http://www.myfitnesspal.com/api and check 'Pull from MFP food database' in the "**API Interest:** " section.

If you're approved and get the API key, then you will want to learn about basic HTTP. Your task requires a GET request, not POST (e.g. you want to GET data from the database, not POST data to the database). And once you're at this stage, you'll want to go back and check out Sumighosh's link again.

Comment: Yes i have submitted a request...but i heard it takes very long or sometimes the never respond...I am wondering if there is any other way :(

Answer (score 0):

if you have an access to the database of the provided website, you can make direct **api calls** from your android application and receive response from the server. or if you are not having access to database **jsoup** is the best option for parsing the html form